# Upgrade went wrong - 18.04 to 20.04 and my laptop isn't working properly

Tags: 20.04, upgrade

So today I decided to upgrade my Ubuntu version from 18.04 to 20.04 and this went super wrong.

After the upgrade,

- **my desktop screen doesn't show any files on it**
- **I open various apps like 'Files' and it immediately closes**
- and generally there have been various bugs.

My files as I see from the terminal are all here but I cant access with any other way other than the Terminal
These are some pictures :
[Terminal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7Lb9E.png)

I couldnt take more because all the apps from the Ubuntu OS would immediatelly close

Is there any way to fix this?

This is the result of the free command to see RAM memory:
[free command](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NHh9F.png)

Comment: I added the result of the free command on the bottom of the post. I dont think RAM is the cause of it but check out the result .Thanks a lot @osakacjupiter

Comment: your RAM is okay friend. the problem is not your RAM. you are right

Comment: thanks a lot mate , is there any way to resolve this? because I dont think anybody is going to answer here @osakacjupiter

Answer (score 0, accepted):

solution #1

it may helps you friend:

```
    sudo apt --fix-broken install
    sudo dpkg --configure -a
    sudo apt upgrade
    sudo reboot
```

solution #2

1-    `sudo rm /var/lib/apt/lists/lock`

2-    `sudo rm /var/lib/dpkg/lock`

3-    `sudo rm /var/lib/dpkg/lock-frontend`

4-    `sudo dpkg --configure -a`

5-    `sudo apt clean`

6-    `sudo apt update --fix-missing`

7-    `sudo apt install -f`

8-    `sudo dpkg --configure -a`

9-    `sudo apt upgrade`

10-    `sudo apt dist-upgrade`

11-    `sudo reboot`

Comment: Did not work my friend but thanks a lot

Comment: Ooo thanks mate #2 solution worked but now I am having another problem. I have now got in a login loop (upgrading from root might be the cause)?

Comment: mate, this might solve your login loop issue: https://www.maketecheasier.com/fix-ubuntu-login-loop/

Comment: Ooo no I tried but I didn't have   . Xauthority file and /tmp was good... Do you have any idea what would help?